# How does Network Manager gets started automatically at boot?

Tags: networking

Can someone let me know how does Network Manager gets started automatically during the system start-up?
Is there any script to do so..? Just curious to know the fact..

Comment: Check out `/etc/init/network-manager.conf`.

Comment: And your configuration - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NetworkManager

Answer (score 0):

`NetworkManager` is a system service. It includes integration with the `init` system to be started on boot.

Per-user programs also exist to talk to this service and provide UI for managing network connections, and can be started in multiple ways, including directly being run by the session manager, or indirectly via the use of [autostart](http://standards.freedesktop.org/autostart-spec/autostart-spec-latest.html) files.